# Nested Predicates In Prolog

Tags: recursion, scope, nested, prolog

I am trying to write a predicate that ‘exists’ inside the ‘scope’ of another predicate . The reason I need this is because both predicates make use of the same very large parameters/arrays and the predicate I want to nest is doing self recurssion many times , so I want to avoid copying the same parameters . So , is there any way i can do this in Swi-Prolg ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you add some example code? That would help us to help you better.

Comment: Can't you simply write something like `Shared = ..., predicate_1(Shared), predicate_2(Shared)` ?

Comment: It is possible to implement [lambda expressions in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56666729/975097), which can be used like nested predicates.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to. You have to realize that all the terms "named" by Prolog variable names are *already global*, although inaccessible when the clause doesn't have a name referencing them (and *names* are always *local to a clause*). That "very large array" is on the heap. Just pass the name to it to any other predicate at ~0 cost.

As Paulo Moura says.

Suppose you have:

```
foo(BigArray) :- do_things(BigArray),do_more_things(BigArray).
```

Suppose `do_things/1` either just prints the element at position 0 if it is an *instantiated term*, or sets it to `bar` if its is a *fresh term*:

```
do_things(BigArray) :- nth0(0,BigArray,Elem),nonvar(Elem),!,write(Elem).
do_things(BigArray) :- nth0(0,BigArray,Elem),var(Elem),!,Elem=bar.
```

If there was a *fresh term* on position 0, the, on return to `foo/1`, the atom `bar` on position 0 is visible to the caller and to `do_more_things/1` because that list designated by `BigArray` is a "global term".

**Some precision on your other question on whether to use "global variables"**:

SWI-Prolog also has "Global Variables", which are apparently similar to the GNU Prolog "Global Variables":

[Global Variables](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar)

We read:

> Global variables are associations between names (atoms) and terms.
>   They differ in various ways from storing information using [`assert/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/1) or
>   [`recorda/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=recorda/3).

...which means that their purpose is similar to the purpose of `assert/1` and `recorda/3`: Storing state that survives query termination at the Prolog toplevel - similar to how program clauses of a program are stored.

I would say, use those only if absolutely needed.

Also read the intro: [Database](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=db), where we find:

> The recorded database is not part of the ISO standard but fairly
>   widely supported, notably in implementations building on the‘Edinburgh
>   tradition'. There are few reasons to use this database in SWI-Prolog
>   due to the good performance of dynamic predicates.